# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv_bridge' IN windows10 running foxy

Tags: ros2, opencv, windows, cv-bridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was following this tutorial https://automaticaddison.com/getting-started-with-opencv-in-ros-2-foxy-fitzroy-python/ to implement a simple ros2 image publisher and subscriber. everything was built but then when I launched the node it gave the error (`cv_bridge not found`).

I am on Windows10 running Ros2 (Foxy).

please help me solve this

PROGRESS....
after that, i found a cv_bridge git repo https://github.com/ros-perception/vision_opencv/tree/ros2
so i cloned it and colcon build it but then it is giving me the following error

```
Starting >>> cv_bridge

--- stderr: cv_bridge

CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):

Could NOT find Boost (missing: Boost_INCLUDE_DIR python3)

Call Stack (most recent call first):

C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)

C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2360 (find_package_handle_standard_args)

CMakeLists.txt:32 (find_package)
```

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/391375/modulenotfounderror:-no-module-named-%27cv_bridge%27-in-windows10-running-foxy/) by [aniketwagh](https://answers.ros.org/users/90068/aniketwagh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2021-11-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is no need to install `cv_bridge` from source if you are using ROS on Windows.

Check `rospack find cv_bridge` if has been properly installed.

Please refer to this thread for more info: https://github.com/ms-iot/ROSOnWindows/issues/317

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2021-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aniketwagh](https://answers.ros.org/users/90068/aniketwagh/) on 2021-12-16**:
Thank you !